# css, table with vertical headers

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to build a table in HTML having its header vertical.
I found exactly what I was looking for there:
http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Fapif

But I cannot reproduce it, and I don't really get why.

My code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        .table-header-rotated {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          .csstransforms & td {
             width: 30px;
          }
          .no-csstransforms & th {
             padding: 5px 10px;
          }
          td {
             text-align: center;
             padding: 10px 5px;
             border: 1px solid #ccc;
          }
          .csstransforms & th.rotate {
             height: 140px;
             white-space: nowrap;
             // Firefox needs the extra DIV for some reason, otherwise the text disappears if you rotate 
             > div {
                transform: 
                  // Magic Numbers
                  translate(25px, 51px)
                  // 45 is really 360-45
                  rotate(315deg);
                width: 30px;
             }
             > div > span {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
                padding: 5px 10px;
             }
          }
          th.row-header {
             padding: 0 10px;
             border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
          }
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<table class="table table-header-rotated">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- First column header is not rotated -->
      <th></th>
      <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
      <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 2</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 3</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 4</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 5</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 6</span></div></th>
    </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="row-header">Row header 1</th>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column1"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row1-column2"></td>
      <td><input name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row1-column3"></td>
      <td><input name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row1-column4"></td>
      <td><input name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row1-column5"></td>
      <td><input name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row1-column6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row-header">Row header 2</th>
      <td><input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row2-column1"></td>
      <td><input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column2"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row2-column3"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row2-column4"></td>
      <td><input name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row2-column5"></td>
      <td><input name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row2-column6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row-header">Row header 3</th>
      <td><input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row3-column1"></td>
      <td><input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row3-column2"></td>
      <td><input name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column3"></td>
      <td><input name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row3-column4"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row3-column5"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row3-column6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Here a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n00tevvs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will work, apply it**

```
th.rotate {
  /* Something you can count on */
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(25px, 51px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}
th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
/* These aren't needed and will be weird if transforms don't work */
.csstransforms & th.rotate {
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***CSS***

```
.table-header-rotated {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-header-rotated td {
  width: 30px;
}
 .table-header-rotated th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table-header-rotated td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
 .table-header-rotated th.rotate {
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
 .table-header-rotated th.rotate > div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
      -ms-transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
          transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}
 .table-header-rotated th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table-header-rotated th.row-header {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n00tevvs/5/)

> Check weather you have SASS code or normal CSS code.